# Insert shape or images inside a table cell?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Is there a way to insert a shape or image inside a table cell?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

[Image][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457710/adding-image-inside-table-cell-in-html

Answer (score 1):

Double click to edit the table cell

[image]

then click the right-most button on the toolbar

[image]

To enter raw HTML mode. There you can set anything that HTML allows you (images yes, draw.io shapes, no).